# Understanding the working of logb()

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to understand the working of  `logb()` , It's [manual](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/logb.3.asp) says "**The logb() function computes exponent of x, which is the integral part of $ \log_r^{|x|} $, as a signed floating point value, for a non-zero x, *where r is the radix of the machine's floating-point* arithmetic."**

I am inquisitive to know to compute this `r` for a particular machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FLT_RADIX` in `<float.h>`. In the real world it's always 2, and IEEE floating point requires it to be 2.

Comment: @R. IEEE 754-2008 actually specifies radix 2 and radix 10 f-p arithmetic.

Comment: However an IEEE 754 conformant C or C++ implementation uses 32-bit and 64-bit (single and double precision) binary floating point for the `float` and `double` types regardless of the existence of decimal extensions. The next C and C++ standards revisions will likely contain new types for decimal floating point.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the [radix](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/sourcepro/edition9/html/stdlibref/numeric-limits.html#idx1035) for a given floating point type on a given machine using the template `std::numeric_limits` from the header `<limits>`.

```
#include <limits>

std::numeric_limits<float>::radix;
```